# Control Visibility LinearLayout with Javascript on Webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a WebView working with JavaScript enabled and i want to call a function via JavaScript inside the WebView that makes the LinearLayout Item gets visible and other function to hide it

This is my working function that make it visible when im loading a new page in WebView

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            findViewById(R.id.cargando).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
```

This is my layout (pretty standar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cargando"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#CC3333"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want something like this that i can call via Javascript:

WebAppInterface.java

```
public class WebAppInterface  extends MainActivity{

    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {

        mContext = c;

    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void mostrar_cargar() {

        findViewById(R.id.cargando).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
}
```

But i'm getting the error

```
Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'
```

I don't know if i need to add something more to the function that will be called via Javascript.

EDIT1:

Now i'm not getting the error after extending my mainactivity but im not getting nothing running after calling the function mostrar_cargar() with JavaScript.

*When i add `final LinearLayout cargando = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cargando);` bellow  `Context mContext;` my app cant run.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://x.x.x.x");
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this),"Android");

      }
}
```

Thanks for any recommendations or solutions.

Comment: The error you're getting is largely unrelated to JavaScript, WebViews and so on. `findViewById` is a method of the `Activity` class, and it will only "work" in an `Activity` class. Edit: checking code of mine, your `mostrar_cargar()` is most likely inside a class you're going to be using as JavaScript interface. Which means you need to use `final LinearLayout cargando = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cargando);` in your Activity class, then call `cargando.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in your method.

Comment: To clarify: when you call `findViewById()`, you are actually calling `this.findViewById()`. However, `this` cannot be any Object, it has to be an instance of the `Activity` class.

Comment: When i add the final LinearLayout ... i cant open my app. It gets an error. I just edit the post with more information about the activities

Comment: Actually, forget what I said and simply move your `WebAppInterface` class definition inside your `MainActivity` class. That way you can use `findViewById()` inside it no problem.